# Rvest Not Finding Anything in X Path

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to run a pretty simple scrape on two tables within the following page:

https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/

My goal is to get the team three letter abbreviation for all teams in both the active teams table and inactive teams table.

I have successfully done so with the first (active) teams with the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

teams_page <- 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/'

# active teams

read_html(teams_page) %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="teams_active"]/tbody') %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = ".//a[@href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  .[str_detect(.,"teams")]
```

After inspecting the html there's a very similar path for "teams_inactive" but for some reason I can't get it to pull anything. Here's what I tried

Try 1

```
read_html(teams_page) %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="teams_inactive"]/tbody') %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = ".//a[@href]")
```

Try 2

```
# inactive teams
read_html(teams_page) %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="all_teams_inactive"]') %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = ".//*[@id='teams_inactive']")
```

I'm still trying to get better at understanding how to navigate html so I bet there's a valuable lesson to be learned here. Perhaps I need to start with a different tag to look for first? Much help would be appreciated and specifically using x path.

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the page source in your browser, you may notice that all that inactive data is embedded in an HTML comment. Since comments can contain any arbitrary text, they are not parsed into the node tree. You cant use xpath in that case. See this existing question about the same site showing one way to parse the data in the comments as a new html source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415445/scraping-lineup-data-from-football-reference-using-r

Comment: Another discussion of that site in particular (using another language than R, but goes into more details about why your first method didn't work) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781357/pro-football-reference-team-stats-xpath